# echo framework, downgrade privileges at which moment?

Tags: go, go-echo

I use [echo framework](https://echo.labstack.com/) for creation of my API server. It is started by **systemd** and needs root by default, in order to aquire ports below 1024. For security I like to **downgrade privileges** of my go program after the listening port has been aquired by echo framework.

I know how to downgrade, but **I can not find a suitable event/callback for this**? The problem is, that `echo.Start()` and `echo.StartAutoTLS()` do not come back. I can create a parallel thread and try to find some status value of my echo session telling me that the port was opened, but I can not find such status indication either.

How can I make sure that I get some code executed after the port is aquired (and know for sure)?

Until now I run a parallel go thread just before server creation and wait 5 seconds to do the downgrade then. It works so far, but this is hacky and I don't like it :-(

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/41248866/13860

Comment: TL;DR; what you're attempting is very difficult to impossible in Go, due to its threading model. It's usually best to use a work-around.

Comment: you could try "ListenerAddr()" it should not return until "Start" has opened the port, as it is locked by "startupMutex"

Comment: @lumos0815 This worked! I do a loop nn my extra thread until it does not return nil. If it comes back, the port was opened and I can downgrade. If you make a separate entry, I can mark it as solution!

This is how I solved:
func degradePrivileges(e *echo.Echo, userName string) {
 for {
  adr := e.ListenerAddr()
  if adr != nil {
   degradeMe(userName)
   break
  }
  time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
 }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use e.ListenerAddr() to check if the port is open.
It will return nil until the port is open.

```
func degradePrivileges(e *echo.Echo, userName string) { 
    for { adr := e.ListenerAddr() if adr != nil { 
        degradeMe(userName) break 
    } 
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond) } 
}
```